# Redirecting multiple old pages to new pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm changing the structure of my pages and I need to re-direct the old ones to the new pages.

Here is an example of some of the following pages I need to move, basically anything in the `pages` folder needs to be moved down, also the old pages always showed the `php` extension.

```
www.example.com/pages/index.php          www.example.com/index
www.example.com/pages/contact_us.php     www.example.com/contact_us
```

Here is what I have so far

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

**Edit**

the rewrite above works but makes pages such as example.com/contact_us unusable, you have to put an extension .php at the end, this is not a problem I had prior to this rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+pages/(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ pages/$1.php [L]
```